# Angular app with custom JS file runs differently on localhost vs on server

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, server, localhost

I have this simple angular app: [janev.ga](http://janev.ga) with a custom JS file for the countdown (I am using the [classycountdown script](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Slick-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Plugin-Classy-Countdown/)).
**THE PROBLEM:** when I run it locally everything loads great, however, once I deployed it to the server I realized it doesn't work the same as my localhost testing. What I mean by that is when I try to access it online, **it would never load the JS script on the first go, even though there are no errors. I have to refresh the page and only then would the countdown script start working**...
The way I use it in the component is by declaring it in angular.json (the custom.js file):

```js
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/custom.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.classycountdown.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.classycountdown.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.knob.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.throttle.js"
            ]
```

, then I use it in the component like this:

```js
declare const myDate: any;

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  myDate = myDate()[0];
  scnds = (myDate()[0] * 86400) - myDate()[1];
  toSec = {
    seconds: this.scnds
  }
}
```

And this is the custom.js:

```js
function myDate(){
  var rightNow = new Date();
  // var theDate = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");
  var goLiveDate = new Date("08/22/2020");
  var Result = Math.round(goLiveDate.getTime() - rightNow.getTime()) / (1000*3600*24);
  var toTheSecond = (rightNow.getHours() * 3600) + (rightNow.getMinutes() * 60) + (rightNow.getSeconds());
  return [Result.toFixed(), toTheSecond];
}

$(document).ready(function() {
          var remainingSec = $('.countdown').data('remaining-sec');
          $('.countdown').ClassyCountdown({
        theme: "flat-colors-very-wide",
        end: $.now() + remainingSec
    });
    });
```

Can anyone suggest what may the problem be? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed one thing today which only appears on the first load of the site. I get this cookie warning: "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://cloudflare.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`..." 

Could that be the reason why the countdown script is not loaded on the initial run?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a ghost town here.. Anyone with a suggestion? Doesn't even have to be the right one.

Comment: The cookie is not the reason for my problem - I removed the cloudflare link and don't get the cookie warning anymore, but the issue persists.
I would love to hear anyone else chime in..
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the whole problem is the loading of this block here:

$(document).ready(function() {
          var remainingSec = $('.countdown').data('remaining-sec');
          $('.countdown').ClassyCountdown({
        theme: "flat-colors-very-wide",
        end: $.now() + remainingSec
    });
});

When the page loads for the first time var remainingSec is unknown, which I am assuming is because the countdown script is not yet loaded... Any ideas how to fix that?